# Создание рамки JDialog

Tags: java, swing

пытаюсь создать свое диалоговое окно

```
public class InformJDialog extends JDialog {
    private String title;

    public InformJDialog(String title) {
        this.title = "<html><font size=6 color=black>"+title;
        this.setSize(180,120);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setModal(true);
        JLabel jLabel=new JLabel(this.title);
        jLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.add(jLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Однако, вместе с кнопками управления отключается и рамка, подскажите, каким образом можно оставить рамку или создать свою. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте свойство Border, например так:

```
 this.getRootPane().
        setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED) );
```